# Installing C++ OpenCV on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking for anyway to set up C++ OpenCV on my mac. I've found numerous articles online but they all end up giving errors of some kind. I am completely indifferent to everything but the C++ part (for example flexible on the use of Xcode). Please don't link an article or post a method unless it has recently worked. I've already gone through tons of those. Any help would be very appreciated, I've been stuck for a couple days on this.

Details: Xcode 5, OS 10.9.4

Off Topic Edit: I realize this is a vague question but I'm not really looking for the best tool or solution. Just any one that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew info opencv
brew install opencv
```

The `info` command was added as a suggestion so that you review the options you have when installing OpenCV. I'm using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: The line "brew install opencv" says permission denied". If I try "sudo brew install" is says "You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk." but then does not allow me to do so anyways.

Comment: @Bren you should have something messed up with `/usr/local`. Homebrew is a tool that will take over that directory, it works by installing all stuff there, so, you should have write permission over it and more, it's recommend you let `/usr/local` solely for homebrew stuff, meaning, before using homebrew `/usr/local` should be empty or non-existent. Because of that, I install custom stuff to `/opt/local` and let `/usr/local` for homebrew stuff.

Comment: @Bren Homebrew is well known in OS X world, if you don't know it you should get some basic information. `brew doctor` is a command that can help in self-diagnostic regarding a healthy homebrew installation.

Comment: So after removing macports I still get this error: "Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py"

Comment: @Bren Sorry, I don't have time to help you in that. My clean slate in OS X is this: after Mavericks install, I installed Xcode and then just homebrew without any issues since OS X by default have no use for /usr/local. Then my preference is to install a recent python, ruby, etc through homebrew itself (I also use pyenv and rbenv, but it's not a must). I make these newer tools the default for my system by changing `/etc/paths`, `~/.profile`, etc.

Comment: @Bren you can check my dotfiles at https://github.com/oblitum/dotfiles. While we were talking homebrew [just finished](http://i.imgur.com/xcpgaBb.png) downloading, building and installing OpenCV and all its dependencies.

Comment: I cleared out some files in usr/local and this worked. Thanks! Now on to solve the Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error.

Comment: @Bren probably you should look how to link to the opencv libraries. The command `brew --prefix opencv` will give you the root directory of installation for opencv, there lies a directory structure with `/bin`, `lib`, etc directories, you should just learn what you have to pass to the compiler and linker to build opencv applications.